# Migrating db of existing project

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rake

I taking over an existing rails project. I currently trying to get the db setup. I have run rake db:create and the DB was created. I need to get the tables created. I have tried db:scheme:load, db:setup and db:migrate. All give me this error:

Mysql2::Error: Table 'blah' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `blahs`

Then a long stack trace with nothing very helpful.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Check the migrations, there would be something like 'blah' (left by developer)

Comment: 'Blah' is not in the migrations. I put that there as a placeholder. Sorry for the confusion.